# How to name rest api urls best practices

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am creating an app where a user is performing some tasks but I am very confused about how to name urls as I can't find a similar tutorials on the internet

1. User is creating a room
2. User is sharing that room link on social sites.
3. People are sending requests to join that room.
4. requests accept.
5. request rejected.
6. get details of the room.
7. per month charges of the room joining.
8. payment send for each room.

   path('api/create-room/', CreateRoomView.as_view(), name="create-room"),

I want my urls like this but I someone told me this is not the best to write it instead I should write in hierarchy. which I am very confused about.

Comment: A REST API is *data-driven*, not *action* drive, so typically one does not name it `create-room/`, but allows to make a POST request to a `room/` endpoint that will create a room.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design and many others documents on the web can show you how to conceptually build REST apis.